# Yet Another Stupid Task.ContinueWith Issue

Tags: c#, async-await, task

The following works :

```
public static void Main( string[] args ){
    Task FooTask = Task.Run( ( ) => Console.WriteLine( "Bar" )
        ).ContinueWith( T => Console.WriteLine( "Baz" ) );
    FooTask.Wait( );
    Console.WriteLine( "Press Enter To Exit." );
    Console.ReadLine( );
}
```

The following does not - ( Bar is printed, Baz is not ).

```
static void printFirstMessage( ){
    console.WriteLine( "Bar" );
}

static void printFirstMessage( ){
    Console.WriteLine( "Baz" );
}

public static void Main( string[] args ){
    //I say "new Action( ... )" because if I don't, I get an IDE error
    //that says "The call is ambiguous between..."
    Task FooTask = Task.Run( new Action( printFirstMessage )
        ).ContinueWith( new Action( printSecondMessage ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "Press Enter To Exit." );
    Console.ReadLine( );
}
```

This is an oversimplification of my real issue where I would like to be able to chain two methods together into a task, then do some other stuff, then `Wait( )` out the task before exiting the method.

Why does the first instance work fine, but the second instance fail?

Comment: Have you tried `Task FooTask = Task.Run( () => printFirstMessage() )
        ).ContinueWith( () => printSecondMessage() );` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContinueWith` doesn't accept an `Action` as the first parameter.  There are in fact quite a lot of different overloads, but all of them accept a delegate that takes a `Task`, along with potentially other parameters, and different overloads of `ContinueWith` have additional parameters besides just a delegate.

If you used `Action<Task>` instead of `Action` (and provided a method with the appropriate signature) then the code would compile, as your first example does.

Comment: So, basically, don't call with new Action( MyMethod ) and just call it with a lambda. I think I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @Will That's not what I said at all.  You're just using the wrong delegate.  `ContinueWith` accepts an `Action<Task>` so you need to pass an `Action<Task>` to it.  By all means, use a lambda to do so, but that doesn't mean you can't explicitly state the delegate, it just means *you need to use the right one*.

Answer (score 1):

> Yet Another Stupid Task.ContinueWith Issue

You shouldn't be using `ContinueWith`. [It's a low-level, inherently dangerous API with several non-obvious pitfalls](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

> Why does the first instance work fine, but the second instance fail?

As Servy answered, it's because `ContinueWith` doesn't take an `Action` parameter - it takes `Action<Task>`. However, this is really the wrong question...

> This is an oversimplification of my real issue where I would like to be able to chain two methods together into a task, then do some other stuff, then Wait( ) out the task before exiting the method.

The proper way to chain is to use `await`:

```
private static async Task DoBothAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Bar"));
  Console.WriteLine("Baz");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task FooTask = DoBothAsync();
  FooTask.Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Also, I find the use of `Task.Run` questionable. It's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have specified in your second example is incorrect and does not even compile.  If you correct the syntax to what I think you are meaning (see below) then the code works the same as the first example:

```
static void printFirstMessage()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Bar");
}

static void printSecondMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Baz");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task FooTask = Task.Run(() => printFirstMessage())
        .ContinueWith(t => printSecondMessage());
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That's what the OP's first example was.  They asked why the second example behaves differently.

Comment: @Servy Yes and it looks like the second example is NOT the same as the first. I think this answer is correct, or at the very least try.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm The question is "Why does A work and B doesn't?" and the answer is, "Use A".  That's obviously not an answer to the question.  The *premise* of the question is that A works, so saying that it works is in no way an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy Ok, but that's how it works. That's like asking why this works `if(1 == 1)` and this doesn't `if(1 == "1")`. Sure, you can go on about why it doesn't work. But the more acceptable would be (IMO), is that you're doing it wrong. Right? The OP is not doing this correctly, and as you so harshly pointed out to me yesterday, why hinder someones understanding of how something should work? A bit of hypocrisy, no?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm If a question asked that then saying, "Do `if(1==1)`" is *not* in fact an answer.  It's just re-stating the question.  The correct answer would be that there is no (build in) way of comparing a string and an integer, so you need to compare the integer to another integer.  *That* answers the question of why the second snippet doesn't work.  Just ignoring the question entirely and re-stating the first half of the question is in no way an answer to that question.  When a question asks, "Why is this wrong" then *explain why it's wrong* rather than repeating the fact that it's wrong.

Comment: @Servy Ok I just think that kevin holditch and I wanted to help the OP actually make it work, instead of *technically* answering the question (even though, we are answering it implicitly).

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm The OP *already knows how to make it work*.  They show how to do so right in their first snippet. How is repeating what they already know being helpful?  And no, this isn't explicitly answering the question. it's not even *implicitly* answering the question.  It's completely ignoring the question, leaving it unanswered, and just repeating the question.  If the question *only* showed the second snippet, and said they couldn't get it working, *then* you might have a point, but the question *already includes all of this information*.

Comment: @Servy And like I said, that's the equivalent of asking why `if(1==1)` works and `if(1=="1")` doesn't. I already know you sit on here all day so I'll let you get the last word after this (seeing as you're unable to let something go and I have actual work to do). But yeah, you can't have it both ways. Sorry. You seem really really really fun and open minded to work with btw, I bet everyone you've worked with is really glad to work with you.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm What are you talking about?  I already explained how you'd answer that example question.  You'd do it by explaining that there's no `==` operator that compares an int and a string.  You wouldn't "answer" it by repeating the first half of the question.  Why do you think repeating a question answers that question?  I don't "want it both ways", I've given the consistent answer to both situations.  My co-workers actually enjoy working with me a lot.  When they ask me a question I actually answer it, rather than just repeating the question and refusing to give them an answer.

Comment: @Servy `You'd do it by explaining that there's no == operator that compares an int and a string.` and theres no way to just call a method inside of an action the way he's doing it. Apples to apples.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm Of course there is.  You just need to use the right delegate.  Providing a methough group, with an explicit delegate conversion, rather than a lambda, is *entirely* fine.  It's what the lambda is going to be converted to under the hood (along with the anonymous method); the lambda is just a shorthand for it.  The OP's code only fails to compile because they assumed `ContinueWith` accepts an `Action`, when in reality it accept an `Action<Task>` (among other possibilities). That trivial change (along with adjusting the method in question) makes the latter approach compile and work.

Answer (score 0):

Task.Run() returns an awaitable Task, which you on which you call ContinueWith. ContinueWith also returns an awaitable Task, which is why you'll need to return something from your ContinueWith call. Try this, which will let you wait for the second task (t) (the printSecondMessage action):

```
Task FooTask = Task.Run(() => printFirstMessage())
                            .ContinueWith(t => printSecondMessage());

FooTask.Wait();
```